# Can i add colour to a relief border to red in a tkinter label

Tags: tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="How to add colour to a relief", relief="solid")
label1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Label parameter there is no option to change the border color, but you can work around that by setting the border width equal to 0 and using frame or highlight

**Frame widget**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+200+200')
border_color = Frame(root, background="red")
label = Label(border_color, text="This is a Label widget", bd=0)
label.pack(padx=1, pady=1)
border_color.pack(padx=40, pady=40)
root.mainloop()
```

**Hightlight**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+200+200')
label1 = Label(root, text="How to add colour to a relief",                                     relief="solid")
label1.config(bd=0, highlightbackground='red', highlightthickness=2)
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```